# How can I solve the problem using super keyword in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, super

```
public class CommissionCompensationModel
{
  private double grossSales;
  private double commissionRate;

  public CommissionCompensationModel(double grossSales, double commissionRate)
  {
    this.grossSales=grossSales;
    this.commissionRate=commissionRate;
  }
}
```

This is my CommissionCompensationModel class

```
public class BasePlusCommissionCompensationModel extends CommissionCompensationModel
{
  protected double baseSalary;

  public void BasePlusCommssionCompenationModel(double grossSales, double commissionRate, double bs)
  {
    **super(grossSales, commissionRate);**
    this.baseSalary=bs;
  }
}
```

This is a subclass of the previous one. It intends to inherit its superclass and add the base salary property. However, the IDE tells me there's some problem with **strong text**. How to solve the problem?

Comment: strong text refers to "super" statement.

Comment: `the IDE tells me there's some problem` What exactly does your IDE tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructors don't have a return type, not even `void`. Additionally, you have a typo there - `BasePlusCommssionCompenationModel` instead of `BasePlusCommissionCompensationModel` (missing an "i" afer the "m"s).

Fix the typo and remove the return type and you should be fine:

```
public BasePlusCommissionCompensationModel(double grossSales, double commissionRate, double bs)
{
    super(grossSales, commissionRate);
    this.baseSalary=bs;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Constructor is written wrong in the subclass.

Constructors can't have a return type not even `void`.

Update to this :

```
class CommissionCompensationModel {
    private double grossSales;
    private double commissionRate;

    public CommissionCompensationModel(double grossSales, double commissionRate) {
        this.grossSales = grossSales;
        this.commissionRate = commissionRate;
    }
}

class BasePlusCommissionCompensationModel extends CommissionCompensationModel {
    
    protected double baseSalary;
    
    public BasePlusCommissionCompensationModel(double grossSales, double commissionRate, double bs) {
        super(grossSales, commissionRate);
        this.baseSalary = bs;
    }

}
```

Comment: @YangXu Is this helpful ?

Comment: Yeah, mainly the typo and "void" return type. Problem Solved thanks.